# How to render a field from loadtree

Tags: theming, entities, taxonomy-terms

Here is my code:

```
   $terms = array(

  \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
      ->getStorage("taxonomy_term")
      ->loadTree('faq', $parent = 0, $max_depth = 1, $load_entities = TRUE)
```

);

and when i'm using kint, i can see the first level of my vocabulary.

[image]

How can i render the field_question_tag in twig?

Comment: $terms->get('field_question_tag')- >getValue();

Comment: thx a lot Vikram8888, but it still doesn't work for me... get method look like unknown... :-/

Answer (score 2):

I Changed how to build my form,

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $terms = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
      ->getStorage("taxonomy_term")
      ->loadTree('faq', $parent = 0, $max_depth = 1, $load_entities = TRUE);
  $terms_select = array();
  foreach ($terms as $term){

      $question = $term->get('field_question_faq')->getValue();

      $terms_select[] =  $question[0]['value']);


  }
```

and then everything was fine!!

Thx to Vikram8888